# Making a TV Remote in iOS

Tags: ios, television

I have a 3.5mm to IR sensor to connect to my headphone jack. I want to know if there's a way to create a basic app for my TV that will control it's Volume, Power On/Off, input, and number pad. I've kept researching for about a week now on how to do this, but haven't found an answer. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Yes is it possible, you only need an application what play wav files.
Or jsut a file browser.

But you can find a plenty of [applications](http://techcrunch.com/2010/07/13/what-can-10-buy-you-a-universal-remote-for-your-iphone/) and [tutorials](http://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-Infrared-transmitter-for-iPhone-iPod) and [details](http://wiki.samygo.tv/index.php5/Remote_Control_emulator%3a_send_custom_IR_codes) all over the internet.